# Unable to implement event subscription in ONVIF

Tags: c#, camera, onvif

I am implementing ONVIF by using Onvif device manager dll  ( onvif.services, discovery, session, and utils.async, common, diagnostic, fsharp dll ).

So far i am able to do discover the onvif devices, getting scopes( device info) and  its profiles, to stream video and implemented the ptz control.

Now I am implementing event subscription but i am unable to subscribe to any specific event.

> Here is my code of event subscription. and i don't know what to do
>   next.

```
OnvifParam deviceparam = ONVIFDevices[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
deviceparam.Account = new NetworkCredential { UserName = "admin", Password = "admin" };
var sessionFactory = new NvtSessionFactory(deviceparam.Account);

int listenport = 8085;
string EventListeningPort = null;
int.TryParse(EventListeningPort, out listenport);
Uri uri = new Uri(deviceparam.Uris[0].ToString());
deviceparam.URL = uri.ToString();
Profile[] profiles = null;
var f = sessionFactory.CreateSession(uri);
profiles = f.GetProfiles().RunSynchronously();
deviceparam.Profiles = profiles;

OdmSession o = new OdmSession(f);

var subs = o.GetBaseEvents(listenport).Subscribe();

var eventprop = f.GetEventProperties();

FilterType filter = new FilterType();
```

Can anyone tell me how to implement event subscription?

Comment: Is this a problem with understanding how ONVIF event subscription works or problem how to code it?

Comment: This question was about how event subscription works. But now i am able to subscribe to the all the events but i am unable to filter out the events.

Comment: You should probably answer your own question if you solved this problem, regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a lot of reading and searching I have implemented Event using Onvif device manager dlls.

**There are three ways by which we can subscribe to the events.**

1.Real time Pull-Point Notification Interface.(Pull-Point Mechanism)

2.Basic Notification  Interface.(Push Mechanism)

3.Notification Streaming Interface. (Metadata streaming)

***Real time Pull-Point Notification Interface***

This interface provides a firewall friendly notification interface. In this client will pull pull event's messages from the camera at regular interval. So we create a pull-point subscription and then pull events from the camera.

> CODE

```
class Events
{
   public void GenerateEvent()
    {
        // for this device must be discoverable and and its account and uri must be known

        var sessionFactory = new NvtSessionFactory(deviceparam.Account); // deviceparam is camera and account contaion its username and password
        var sess = sessionFactory.CreateSession(uri);
        OdmSession os = new OdmSession(sess);
        os.GetPullPointEvents()// this function contains function for the subscription and pull messages
            .Subscribe(
            evnt =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(EventParse.ParseTopic(evnt.topic));
                var messages = EventParse.ParseMessage(evnt.message);
                messages.ForEach(msg => Console.WriteLine(msg));
            }, err =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
            }
            );

    } 
}

public static class EventParse
{
    public static string ParseTopic(TopicExpressionType topic) 
    {
        string topicString = "";

        topic.Any.ForEach(node => {
            topicString += "value: " + node.Value;
            });

            return topicString;
    }

    public static string[] ParseMessage(Message message) 
    {
        List<string> messageStrings = new List<string>();

        messageStrings.Add("messge id: " + message.key);

        if(message.source!= null)
            message.source.simpleItem.ForEach(sitem => 
            {
                string txt = sitem.name + " " + sitem.value;
                messageStrings.Add(txt);
            });

        if (message.data != null)
            message.data.simpleItem.ForEach(sitem => 
            {
                string txt = sitem.name + " " + sitem.value;
                messageStrings.Add(txt);
            });

        return messageStrings.ToArray();
    }
}
```

***Basic Notification  Interface.(Push Mechanism)***

In this Interface camera will notify the client about the event. The connection on which the Notification is sent is initiated by the camera and established on TCP protocol, So we need permission of firewall here.

Advantage of this interface is client does not need to be the same entity that sets up the subscription, i.e camera can send the event to any client after the subscription has done.

> CODE

```
class Events
{
    public void GenerateBaseEvent()
    {
        // for this device must be discoverable and and its account and uri must be known

        var sessionFactory = new NvtSessionFactory(deviceparam.Account); // deviceparam is camera and account contaion its username and password
        var sess = sessionFactory.CreateSession(uri);
        OdmSession os = new OdmSession(sess);
        os.GetBaseEvents(9865)// some random port number
            .Subscribe(
            evnt =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(EventParse.ParseTopic(evnt.topic));
                var messages = EventParse.ParseMessage(evnt.message);
                messages.ForEach(msg => Console.WriteLine(msg));
            }, err =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
            }
            );

    }
}
```

***Notification Streaming Interface***

In this interface we receive event notifications in real-time over an RTP or RTSP stream. First, a media profile is set up that contains a MetadataConfiguration with the desired event filter. After that, the stream
URI for that profile can be fetched and used.

I haven't tried this interface yet.

*Above code doesn't have filter so it will give notification for all the events.*